# Error in SQLiteDatabase Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently Im am implementing SQLiteDatabase into my android application. So i wanted to create a table called TABLE_LOGIN and store all the data of the login user but i met with a error saying 1 of the column doesnt exist. I check and i did put the column when the table is created
Below is my code:

```
// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_CNAME = "cname";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
08-27 01:29:57.336: E/JSON(531): {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"5033b1eeedde88.60881196","user":{"name":"a","cname":"a","email":"a@gmail.com","created_at":"2012-08-22 00:06:06","updated_at":null}}
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531): Error inserting uid=5033b1eeedde88.60881196 created_at=2012-08-22 00:06:06 email=a@gmail.com cname=a name=a
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named cname: , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(uid, created_at, email, cname, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.library.DatabaseHandlerEmployer.addUser(DatabaseHandlerEmployer.java:72)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.LoginEmployerActivity$LoginEmployer$1.run(LoginEmployerActivity.java:129)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-27 01:29:57.486: E/Database(531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem/com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.HomepageEmployerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.HomepageEmployerActivity.onDestroy(HomepageEmployerActivity.java:315)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
08-27 01:29:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  ... 11 more
```

***EDIT*** INSERT USER DATA CODE:

```
public void addUser(String name, String cname, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_CNAME, cname); // CName
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // UID
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: Could you also show the code which you used for inserting

Comment: @nandeesh what you mean by clear the app data?

Comment: @knightrider uploaded the code

Comment: Settings->applications -> select your app -> Clear data, or if you have a drop table sqlite statement in onUpgrade just increment the database version

Comment: @nandeesh I clear data still crash. I have a onupgrade method where my code drop table is exists and increase the version

Comment: it might not be related but could you post ondestroy also and point line 315?

Comment: the on destroy got nothing to do with the error because that is my search function

Comment: could be but but thr is a crash pointing to it

Comment: @JonesCh Have you checked the structure of database?

Comment: @nandeesh this is my onDestroy protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
 }

Comment: @knightrider what you mean? sorry im just started learning so need some help

Comment: searchBarEmployer is it initialized? try removing it for now and check once

Comment: @nandeesh ya global private EditText searchBarEmployer;

Comment: @JonesCh I mean have you checked the column names in the created table. Try to display its table structure

Comment: I think its null, remove that line and check

Comment: @knightrider how to display the table structure?

Comment: remove the searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);  line in Ondestroy

Comment: @JonesCh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382528/how-to-get-a-tables-columns-arraylist-on-android/2383705#2383705

Comment: @knightrider where do i display out to? android?

Comment: @JonesCh if you are using an emulator, just output it to log

Comment: What is the value of TABLE_LOGIN? Is it `login`?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor ti = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(TABLE_LOGIN)", null); 
     if ( ti.moveToFirst() ) { 
         do { 
             Log.d(ti.getString(1), "column"); 
         } while (ti.moveToNext()); 
     }
Im using this method but i cant get it to display in logcat

Comment: @iturki ya i declared it

Comment: the error keep telling me that the login table has no column name cname

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it; comments are not easy for users to look through to see what's going on with the state of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** -> **Manage Applications** -> **Your Application** -> **Clear all application data**.

*Maybe* it is using an old table stored in the phone before you added this column in your table.

***EDIT*** : I think there is a slight problem with the String concatenation that you are using.

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
      + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_CNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_EMAIL+" TEXT UNIQUE, "+KEY_UID+" TEXT, "+KEY_CREATED_AT+" TEXT)";
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try the query that I have written.

Comment: Its still saying that my table_login has no column name cname

Comment: Is cname the only column that it says is missing ?

Comment: ya if i remove it from the addUser method it wont have error. i still dont know understand why is it still having error when i declare it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't read the whole log cat because I can't scroll it in the browser of my phone but I think the problem is the column id.
I think a column thet is set to primary key is automaticly set to not null right? I cam't see that you give a value to this column in the insert command.

If this suggestion is right it would help to set the column to autoincrememt. If you would like to use the table in a listview change the name to _id.